# Когда полезна дефрагментация диска?

Tags: диск

Есть разные варианты дисков:

- обычные диски,
- флэш-диски,
- RAID-массивы,
- диски в памяти.

Известно, что для обычных дисков дефрагментация полезна: она ускоряет скорость чтения и записи файлов. Будет ли сопоставимое ускорение для флэш, RAID и т.п.?

Comment: Полезна всегда и для всего

Answer (score 1):

Дефрагментация нужна для всех дисков потому что скорость доступа повышается т.к. блоки памяти идут друг за другом и проц и.т.п не обрабатывает лишние действия

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с Serg.В моём случаем, я пользуюсь программой SmartDefrag2. У меня стоит дефрагментация системных файлов при запуске и дефрагментация во время простоя системы. Много времени ушло на дефрагментацию в первый раз.

Answer (score 0):

Программ для дефрагментации есть много, но...

Я слышал, что часто делать эту операцию нельзя, т.к. изнашивается и приходит в негодность механика ЖД!

Answer (score 0):

Дефрагментация имеет смысл только для носителей с подвижными механическими считывателями, так-как группируя информацию, мы повышаем скорость последовательного чтения блока, давая возможность головке считывать подряд несколько блоков одного файла.

На флешнакопителях, в силу отсутствия читающей головки такие операции сомнительны и могут напротив ухудшить состояние носителя, учитывая довольно известную ограниченность циклов запись-перезапись.

Организация в массивы не меняет отношение к дискам, то есть они работают так же, как и в одиночку: механика требует дефрагментации, электроника - нет.
Стоит отметить, что массивы более подвержены фрагментации, но при правильной работе массива и использовании умного дефрагментатора, можно ускорить работу за счёт параллельности считывания и записи.

Диски в памяти - вопрос риторический, если прочитать внимательно выше.